# isometric isomorphism between normed spaces and its dual

Tags: analysis, functional-analysis, operator-theory, banach-spaces

Let $E$ and $F$ be normed spaces.  If $E \equiv F$ (isometry isomorphic),

Does $E^* \equiv F^*$ (isometry isomorphic)?

Where $E^*$ and $F^*$ are continuous dual spaces.

Comment: Hint: suppose $T : E \to F$ is an isometric isomorphism.  Consider the adjoint $T^* : F^* \to E^*$ defined by $(T^* \ell)(e) = \ell(Te)$.

Comment: Thank you for your hint, but what about the other hand (T*)^-1 from E* into F* is also isometry isomorphic ?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. The inverse of any isometric isomorphism is an isometric  isomorphism. Maybe you should edit the question to show what you have done so far and where you are stuck.

Comment: I mean by the following example. the dual space of lp is isometric isomorphic to lq, where 1/p + 1/q=1. In the proof he define a map f from (lp)* into lq and proves f is bijective and preserve the homomorphism and isometry property and he told now conversely define another map say g from lq into (lp)* and proves also g is bijective and preserve the homomorphism and isometry property.

Comment: Now relevant to my question You answer me to define a dual operator from F* into E* to be bijective and preserve the homomorphism and isometry property, so building upon to the above example we need also another function say g from E* into F* and prove g is bijective and preserve the homomorphism and isometry property this is what I meant. Is this true or just to define function in our case the dual operator to prove that E* equivalent to F*.